# A simple Pygame that has a square move and jump

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, pygame

How does this Pygame code look? Is the run loop usually in a class? I'm a beginner and was wondering what the best format and structure is for using OOP in Pygame.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500)) 
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")


class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 250
        self.y = 250
        self.width = 50
        self.height = 50
        self.vel = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.jumpCount = 10

    def run(self):
        run = True
        while run:
            pygame.time.delay(30)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    run = False

            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and self.x > 0:
                self.x -= self.vel

            if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and self.x < 500 - self.width:
                self.x += self.vel

            if not self.isJump:
                if keys[pygame.K_UP] and self.y > 0:
                    self.y -= self.vel

                if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and self.y < 500 - self.height:
                    self.y += self.vel

                if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                    self.isJump = True
            else:
                if self.jumpCount >= -10:
                    self.y -= (self.jumpCount * abs(self.jumpCount)) * 0.5
                    self.jumpCount -= 1
                else:
                    self.jumpCount = 10
                    self.isJump = False

            win.fill((0, 0, 0))
            self.draw()

        pygame.quit()

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 255), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        pygame.display.update()

g = Game()
g.run()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). I have rolled back Rev 3 → 2

Answer (score 2):

Few areas to improve:

- `self.vel`. When I first saw this field/variable I thought: "What is that?".
  I guess many other people may have the same first feeling.
  I would rename it to an explicit and clear name: `self.velocity`
- `self.isJump` and `self.jumpCount` violate Python naming conventions (*instance variable names should be all **lower case**, words in an instance variable name should be separated by an **underscore***). Therefore, rename them to:

  ```
  ...
  self.is_jump
  self.jump_count`
  ```
- `run = True` flag. That flag for just controlling the `while` loop flow is redundant.
  We're just starting the loop with `while True:` and breaking it with `break`.
  So it becomes:

  ```
  def run(self):
      while True:
          pygame.time.delay(30)                
          keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

          # handling pressed keys
          if keys ...

          win.fill((0, 0, 0))
          self.draw()

          for event in pygame.event.get():
              if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                  break
      pygame.quit()
  ```

Comment: I get your last point. In my opinion, having `while run:` makes it easier to understand what the loop is doing.

Comment: @TommyShelburne I can understand that, but you're creating an unnecessary variable to hold a boolean. With a `while True:`, you can simply `break` when needed, instead of setting the flag to `False` and maybe allowing code after it to run.

Answer (score 2):

## *This answer pertains to using `while run` vs `while True`.*

Lets say you have this code:

```
run = True
    count = 0
    while run:
        if count == 5:
            run = False
        count += 1
        print(count)
```

Simple enough code. When viewing it as this, a programmer might see that the code will stop when `count` reaches `5`. Lets look at the output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Woah, whats this? `6` was printed even though the program was supposed to stop at `5`. This happens because even though `run` is now `False`, it doesn't immediately exit the loop. This prevents the *next iteration* from running. So, any code in the rest of the loop will run regardless of what `run` is.

Now lets look at using `while True`:

```
count = 0
while True:
    if count == 5:
        break
    count += 1
    print(count)
```

And the output

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

The `break` *immediately* exits the loop, preventing `count` from being incremented a final time.